# How to def Future onSuccess recursion to tailrec?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I don't know how to description exactly, see the code please

```
def callForever(f: Future[Int]): Unit = {
  f.onComplete {
    case Failure(e) =>
      //do something
    case Success(c) =>
      // do again 
      val nextConn: Future[Int] = connection()
      callForever(nextConn)
  }
}
```

Its a normal recursion,actually,I use it to listen socket wait a Async connection.
Because it always running I want make it better, can I refactor it by a tailrec way?

Comment: I think it is not recursion at all - you are queueing the onComplete handler, not calling it.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `Iterator.continually` maybe in conjunction with `Future.traverse` or `Future.sequence`.

Comment: It's "stackoverflow-safe" already, as every next callForever is gonna be called in "another" thread and as a result - in another stack. To be more precise, it might be the same thread but only after the previous `callForever` returns (so stack is clean). Why is it happening so? `onComplete` just registers a handler and puts it to the thread-pool, so new `callForever` calculation isn't taking a place inside the method's context - it executes directly by threadpoolexecutor.

Comment: @dk14, oh, I'm sudden find it will return immediately. That's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought that you may want to look at this way to do this which looks a bit better for me:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Random}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

/**
  * Created by Alex on 2/29/2016.
  */
object Test {

  def giveMeValue:Future[Int] = Future.successful{Random.nextInt()}

  def callForever(f:Future[Int]):Future[Int] = {
    println("iteration")
    f flatMap(i => {println(i); callForever(giveMeValue)})
  }



  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    callForever(giveMeValue)
    while(true){}
  }

}
```

Comment: To be honest, I was afraid of the endless recursive will hold my stack at beginning but I seems the function will return immediately.The flapMap is also onSuccess and pretty ~ thanks.